# Match line with specific string to extract values Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am having some issues in finding the correct regex for this task, excuse me for my beginner skills. What I am trying to do is only get the id value from a line where its "available":true not "available":false. I am able to get the ID's of all lines through `re.findall('"id":(\d{13})', line, re.DOTALL)` (13 is to match exactly 13 digits, as there are other ids in the code with less than 13 digits which i dont need).

```
{"id":1351572979731,"parent_pid":21741,"available":false,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""},
{"id":1351572329731,"parent_pid":21741,"available":false,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""},
{"id":1351572943231,"parent_pid":21741,"available":true,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""},
{"id":1651572973431,"parent_pid":21741,"available":true,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""},
```

Therefore end results needs to be ['1651572973431','1351572943231']

Appreciate the great help thanks

Comment: Why would you use a regex for this? Is there a reason why you don't parse the JSON instead?

Comment: @CertainPerformance the code is in a html source code inside a <script tag>

Comment: @ggorlen please put the original code back as the outcome doesnt look like that on the code

Comment: You're welcome to roll it back if I inadvertently conflicted with your intent, but if your original structure is a string, please use quotes.

Comment: These two items `['1651572973431','1351572943231']` are distinct. What's the significance of that, since there are other duplicate id's as well ?

Comment: please look at source code of this page https://renarts.com/collections/new-arrivals-footwear/products/kids-air-jordan-11-retro-low-gs-light-bone-cd6847-002 and search for "available":false youll see what type of string it is in

Comment: @sln no id is duplicate, there are all different, i just need the ids which are available=true they are the significant ones for me

Comment: So you're saying that, yes, this is a raw string? If you're asking for a string parsing task, please post *the exact string*, with quotes around it so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: yes right @ggorlen the code in the post now looks fine, please view given link for example code

Comment: The code in the HTML has a similar structure to this, but when I search that code for even a single line of your "string" in it, I see nothing. Therefore, it seems ambiguous to me. In any case, it seems like other folks understand your intent.

Comment: @ggorlen i have just simplified the code by removing some variables which are of no significance search for "available":false in the html youll see an example line, thanks for your consideration :)

Comment: @sakow0 I think there's some confusion because it's not clear if the code above represents a single string or a list of strings. Your regex looks like it is looking at variable called `line`. Is `line` one of these or all of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works to match what you want

`(?<="id":)\d{13}(?=(?:,"[^"]*":[^,]*?)*?,"available":true)`

https://regex101.com/r/FseimH/1

Expanded

```
 (?<= "id": )
 \d{13} 
 (?=
      (?: ," [^"]* ": [^,]*? )*?
      ,"available":true
 )
```

Explained

```
 (?<= "id": )                        # Lookbehind assertion for id
 \d{13}                              # Consume 13 digit id
 (?=                                 # Lookahead assertion
      (?:                                 # Optional sequence
           ,                                   # comma
           " [^"]* "                           # quoted string
           :                                   # colon
           [^,]*?                              # optional non-comma's
      )*?                                 # End sequence, do 0 to many times - 
      ,"available":true                   # until we find  available = true
 )
```

Comment: could you please explain what third part of regex is doing

Comment: @PIG - I've added more. What exactly are you having trouble understanding ?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be a good answer — it depends on exactly what you have. It *looks* like you have a list of strings and you want the id's from some of them. If that's the case, it's going to be *much* cleaner and easier to read if you parse the JSON rather than writing an byzantine regex. For example:

```
import json

# lines is a list of strings:

lines = ['{"id":1351572979731,"parent_pid":21741,"available":false,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""}',
'{"id":1351572329731,"parent_pid":21741,"available":false,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""}',
'{"id":1351572943231,"parent_pid":21741,"available":true,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""}',
'{"id":1651572973431,"parent_pid":21741,"available":true,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""}',
]

# parse it and you can use regular python to get what you want:
[line['id'] for line in map(json.loads, lines) if line['available']]
```

**result**

```
[1351572943231, 1651572973431]
```

If the code you posted is one long string, you can wrap it in `[]` and then parse it as an array with the same result:

```
import json

line = r'{"id":1351572979731,"parent_pid":21741,"available":false,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""}, {"id":1351572329731,"parent_pid":21741,"available":false,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""}, {"id":1351572943231,"parent_pid":21741,"available":true,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""},{"id":1651572973431,"parent_pid":21741,"available":true,"lou":"678","feature":true,"pub":true,"require":null,"option4":""}'

lines = json.loads('[' + line + ']')
[line['id'] for line in lines if line['available']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Mark Meyer this would have been a perfect answer if the data would be whole json, thats my fault for not explaining too well, however i have definitely learnt something from this, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can simply use the "id" as a left boundary, and collect the desired numbers in a capturing group:

```
"id":([0-9]+)
```

[image]

Then, we can continue add boundaries to it. For example, if 13 digits are desired, we can simply:

```
\"id\":([0-9]{13})
```

Comment: The OP only wants rows matching a certain condition.

Comment: Thanks for the response emma, i need to match "available":true condition